# Multiple entry points in SeedStack application

Tags: build, issue-tracking, seedstack

When I try to launch my SeedStack application, I get the following error:

```
org.seedstack.seed.SeedException: [CORE] Multiple seedstack launchers

Description
-----------
There are multiple SeedStack entry points in the classpath.

Fix
---
Exactly one class implementing 'org.seedstack.seed.spi.SeedLauncher' should be present in the classpath and registered in
META-INF/services. Remove all but one launcher.
```

What is the cause of this and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

A `SeedLauncher` is used to launch a particular kind of application (Web app, CLI app, ...). A SeedStack module can only be of one kind at a time.
The error above occurs when you have multiple active implementation of the `SeedLauncher` interface in your classpath. By active I mean present and registered as a service in `META-INF/service`.

The most common cause is when you have the `seed-web-undertow` and the `seed-cli` dependencies in the classpath at the same time, as both provide their own implementation of `SeedLauncher`.

You have to choose if your module should be a CLI application or a Web application and remove the useless dependency. If you want to build both kinds, you'll have to separate them in different modules.

Some add-ons can also provide launcher which can interfere in the same way. If the quick solution above doesn't resolve your problem, use your IDE to find all implementations of the `SeedLauncher` interface and re-organize your modules to have only one launcher per module.